# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper, jsonparser

How to Serialize and de-serialize below object using jackson library ?

```
public class Notification2 implements Serializable {
    private String eventTypeName;
    private TerminationPoint_T tpObj;
    

    public Notification2() {
    }

        
    public TerminationPoint_T getTpObj() {
        return tpObj;
    }

    public void setTpObj(TerminationPoint_T tpObj) {
        this.tpObj = tpObj;
    }

    
}

public final class TerminationPoint_T
    implements org.omg.CORBA.portable.IDLEntity
{
    
    
    public org.tmforum.mtnm.terminationPoint.TPType_T type;
    
    public TerminationPoint_T( org.tmforum.mtnm.terminationPoint.TPType_T type)
    {
        
        this.type = type;
        
    }
}
```

### ERROR:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `org.tmforum.mtnm.terminationPoint.TPType_T` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
at [Source: (String)

Comment: Please note that I don't have control over TerminationPoint_T and TPType_T class

Comment: Google for "Jackson custom serializer for class"

Comment: Hi @Jorn Thanks for your advise but I couldn't find any relevant answer so posted here.

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization